# HC-05 Bluetooth module does not send or receive data when its on-board light blinks(light blinking after its connected to a device)

Tags: arduino-uno, hc-05

HC-05 Bluetooth module does not send or receive data when its on-board light blinks(light blinking after its connected to a device)
as soon as the on-board led starts glowing it does not send or receive data but when the light turns off it works perfectly.

Comment: do you have a question?

Comment: I have a HC-06 (which is the same chip as HC-05, just a different firmware), whose light turns off, when a device is connected. Generally the LED should show the connection state, thus only one of the LED states corresponds to a successfull connection